# Same type, all defined, types conflict

Tags: c, gcc

After some hours of searches I did not found a solution to my problem, which I will explain below.
For now, these are my source and headers file

timer.h:

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

#include "types.h"

uint64 timer_ticks;

void init_timer(uint32 freq);

void wait(uint64 ticks);

void wait_s(uint64 seconds);

void timer_h(struct regs* r);

#endif TIMER_H
```

timer.c

```
 #include "../headers/timer.h"

void init_timer(uint32 freq){
    timer_ticks=0;
    irq_set_handler(0,timer_h);
}

void wait(uint64 ticks){
    uint64 over_ticks=ticks+timer_ticks;
    while(timer_ticks<over_ticks);
}

void wait_s(uint64 seconds){
    uint64 over_ticks=18*seconds;
    wait(over_ticks);
}

void timer_h(struct regs* r){
    timer_ticks++;
}
```

As you have seen, all is correctly defined, but I get this error from the compiler(I use GCC-8.2)

```
include/src/timer.c:21:6: error: conflicting types for 'timer_h'
 void timer_h(struct regs* r){
      ^~~~~~~
In file included from include/src/timer.c:1:
include/src/../headers/timer.h:14:6: note: previous declaration of 'timer_h' was here
 void timer_h(struct regs* r);
      ^~~~~~~
```

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is in `types.h`?

Comment: Nothing important, all my defined types, but the problem is not there cause no problem is present in the other code

Comment: There is no error if I guess the contents: https://godbolt.org/z/R1r1an

Comment: What is `uint64`, etc.? Don't use homebrew types where standard types are available. And use `extern` for prototypes in the header.

Comment: regarding: `void wait(uint64 ticks);`  the function: `wait()` is a well known function, usually used to wait for a child process to exit.  It is found in: the header file: `sys/wait.h`

Comment: regarding: `include/src/timer.c:21:6: error: conflicting types for 'timer_h'
 void timer_h(struct regs* r){`   This looks like your OS is *windows* which does not differentiate between upper and lower case

Comment: The whole project is built standing on no library

Comment: regarding: `include/src/timer.c:21:6` from the error message.  The posted code for `timer.c` does not have the indicated statement at line 21.   Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the problem

Comment: @user3629249 Nope, I'm using Linux. The error is not in the line 21 because I deleted some void lines in the question

Comment: regarding: `#endif TIMER_H`   this should be: `#endif // TIMER_H`

Comment: this line: `void init_timer(uint32 freq){`  should have the next line be: `(void)freq;`

Comment: this line: `void timer_h(struct regs* r){` should be followed by `(void)r;`

Comment: When posting messages from the compiler and/or from some tool, ALWAYS post the same code the tool was used on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `struct regs;` beforehand, otherwise:

> timer.c:21:21: warning: declaration of 'struct regs' will not be
>   visible outside of this function
>         [-Wvisibility]

and therefore every struct regs would be a distinct type. Turn on warnings to have the compiler spot such issues for you.